# How update StatusStripLabel from another class?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing an application in which a data is received from SerialPort. This data is updated on a TextView. I use the following code from another class.

> ```
> _displayWindow.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate
> {
>   _displayWindow.SelectedText = string.Empty;
>   _displayWindow.AppendText(msg);
>   _displayWindow.ScrollToCaret();
> }));
> ```

But now I will not put it in a TextView,  this data will be placed in a ToolStripLabel but ToolStripLabel  it has no Invoke .

Is there a way to update ToolStripLabel?

UPDATE:
This is the complete method

```
private void DisplayData(string msg)
{
  _displayWindow.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate
  {
     _displayWindow.SelectedText = string.Empty;
     _displayWindow.AppendText(msg);
    _displayWindow.ScrollToCaret();
  }));
}
```

I work in Framework 4.5

Comment: Use its Owner property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
    // update toolstriplabel here
});
```

I don't know your framework version. I found this link that could be of interest for you: [How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)